# What was the first story in which crucifixes burned vampires?

Tags: history-of, vampire, religion, undead

In many stories, crosses or other religious symbols hurt vampires.

- In the *Shadowhunters* books by Cassandra Clare, vampires are weak to whatever religious symbols they believe in.
- In *Buffy the Vampire Slayer*, vampires are specifically vulnerable to crosses.
- In *Dungeons & Dragons*, vampires, or indeed any undead, can be driven off or turned to dust by a (non-evil) cleric presenting their religious symbol.
- In the *Dresden Files*, vampires can be repelled by any symbol backed up by genuine faith.

And of course, the big one:

- In *Dracula*, one of the earliest vampire stories, crosses (generally a crucifix) are anathema to the undead.

**What is the first story that featured a religious symbol (most likely a crucifix) being proof against vampires or vampiric (i.e. bloodsucking) entities?** Was it Dracula, or something earlier?

Comment: @anaranjada -If you can find a *specific* folklore story written down, it's fair game. "In Romanian folklore, vampires are vulnerable to crosses" isn't quite what I'm looking for.

Comment: Note that crosses and crucifixes are not the same, and in *Buffy* a cross (without any crucifixion) was definitely sufficient to harm a vampire.

Comment: @ToddWilcox -True, I know that.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Honestly, *[Dracula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dracula)* by Bram Stoker (1897) seems to be the earliest work I've found where the vampires are warded off by a cross. Varney, one of the predecessors to Dracula, was specifically noted to not be bothered by them. There's probably folklore associated with [apotropaic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apotropaic_magic) wardings of vampires, but I have not found them yet. As a side note, it does not match your title, as it only warded off Dracula, although a consecrated Communion wafer burned Lucy when pressed on her forehead.